# Adding a Texture to a Sphere in SlimDX

Tags: geometry, directx, textures, slimdx

I just can't figure out how to apply a texture to a sphere mesh (created with Mesh.CreateSphere). I guess the problem is that those meshes created with Mesh.Create don't have texture coordinates (or do they have some?) and I just can't find out how to add them. I already found some example code for MDX but they use a CustomVertex structure which is not availible in slimDX. Is adding Textures to a standard mesh that difficult? I wonder why there aren't some pre-defined functions in slimDX to do that...
Thanks for your advice.

(p.s. I'm using Direct3D9)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. There are no texture coordinates in the mesh. Instead of inserting the coordinates, it would be easier to create the whole sphere with your custom vertex format.

To create a vertex format, you need a structure to store your vertex data in. E.g. this:

```
public struct MyVertex
{
    public Vector3 Position;
    public static readonly VertexFormat = VertexFormat.Position;
}
```

This will enable you to create Vertexbuffers.

Btw, a sphere is described using two parameters u and v by `p = r * new Vector3(sin(u) * cos(v), sin(u)* sin(v), cos(u));` with u from 0 to Pi and v from 0 to 2*Pi